# MySQL: how to use COALESCE

Tags: mysql, coalesce

Say I have the following table:

```
TABLE: product
===============================================================================
| product_id | language_id | name           | description                     |
===============================================================================
| 1          | 1           | Widget 1       | Really nice widget. Buy it now! |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2           | Lorem  1       |                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I query this such that it tries to give me the `name` and `description` where `language_id` = 2, but fall back to `language_id` = 1 if the column contains a NULL?

In the above example, I should get `Lorem 1` for `name` and `Really nice widget. Buy it now!` for `description`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
SET @pid := 1, @lid := 2;
SELECT 
    COALESCE(name,(
        SELECT name
        FROM product
        WHERE product_id = @pid AND description IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 1
    )) name, 
    COALESCE(description,(
        SELECT description
        FROM product
        WHERE product_id = @pid AND description IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 1
    )) description
FROM product
WHERE product_id = @pid 
    AND (language_id = @lid 
    OR language_id = 1)
ORDER BY language_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

where:

- `@pid`: current product id
- `@lid`: current language id
- Values for `name` and/or `description` could be null
- `language_id` = 2 item could not exist

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, description from product
where product_id = @pid
  and name is not null
  and description is not null
  and (language_id = @lang or language_id = 1)
order by language_id desc
```

where `@pid` is the current product id and `@lang` is the current language id.

The first row returned will contain the current name and description.

This assumes that the row `language_id = 1` will NOT contain `NULL` in name or description.

Comment: and how does this handle NULL columns? Will this fallback to language_id=1's value?

Comment: Sorry, did not see the NULL requirement.  I'll edit the select stmt.

Comment: NULLs are expected values of the columns.

Comment: Im getting all languages

Answer (score 0):

```
select p2.product_id
      ,coalesce(p2.name, p1.name, 'No name') as name
      ,coalesce(p2.description, p1.description, 'No description') as description
  from product p2
  left join product p1 on(
       p1.product_id = p2.product_id
   and p1.language_id = 1
  )
 where p2.product_id  = 1
   and p2.language_id = 2;
```

**Edit1:**
The above query assumes that the language=2 row exist but that the name/descr may be null.

**Edit 2.**
I just remembered someone asked a similar question recently. And then I discovered it was **you**. You need to separate the products from the translations. That is what is making this query hard to write. [Thomas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559342/database-design-how-to-support-multi-lingual-site) makes it easy to do what you want.

Comment: Dude this is really crappy thinking. Go to sleep Ronnis!

Comment: what if language=2 does not exist? No guarantee it will exist, actually.

Comment: the questions were different. The previous question dealt with modeling. Thomas provided a suggestion on how to model and query the data. I've decided to use a modeling approach that differs from Thomas' suggestion. Now, I need to be able to query this in a similar way Thomas' suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: There is an entry for each product with `language = 1`
The code below is just simple sql to retrieve what you want.

Another topic is if you want the behaviour you requested.. because you can have mixed languages between `name` and `description`. I would design it differently, if one of the two fields is empty I would default back to the main language (1).

```
select p.product_id,
  coalesce(pl.name, p.name, 'No name') as name,
  coalesce(pl.description, p.description, 'No description') as description
from product p
  left join product pl on (pl.product_id = p.product_id and pl.language_id = :language_id)
where p.product_id = :product_id and p.language_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using with SQL Update:

Its like equivalent to Oracle's NVL.
You can use it like below in a prepared statement using parameters

```
UPDATE
    tbl_cccustomerinfo
SET
    customerAddress = COALESCE(?,customerAddress),
    customerName =  COALESCE(?,customerName),
    description =  COALESCE(?,description)
WHERE
    contactNumber=?
```